# Bootstrap nav.pills issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code for some nav pills within my homepage,

```
   <div class="menu row-fluid text-center">
            <div class="span12">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
                    <li><a href='/report/' data-toggle="tab">Report</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/cachecheck/' data-toggle="tab">CacheCheck</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/lookup/' data-toggle="tab">Lookup</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

However when I click on one of the links I get the error,

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /report/
```

... and it doesnt take me to the link. Am I missing something simple here ?

Comment: Try change "{% url "dnsdonkey.views.report_input" %}" into '{% url "dnsdonkey.views.report_input" %}'

Comment: Thanks, but unfortanlty that didnt work.

Comment: What do you see in the href value in your HTML page markup?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `data-toggle="tab"` in your links, bootstrap thinks these are tab headers for a tabbed display, and that the `href`'s you give are ID's of the tab pane to show.

Remove `data-toggle="tab"` from your links.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I know, you have to use the href value with # (pound) sign following with id.

```
            <div class="span12">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
                    <li><a href='#report' data-toggle="tab">Report</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#cachecheck' data-toggle="tab">CacheCheck</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#lookup' data-toggle="tab">Lookup</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Pu6jJ/

## EDIT (based on conversation below:)

If you wanted to have only styles, not the tab functionality - remove the data-toggle attribute.

```
            <div class="span12">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
                    <li><a href='/report/'>Report</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/cachecheck/' >CacheCheck</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/lookup/'>Lookup</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

That's all!

Comment: but then this doesnt take you to the link ??

Comment: You want to go to different page?

Comment: Yep each "pill" should allow me to click onto a different page.

Comment: Are you using that nav-pills or nav or center-pills classes just for look/design not for the tab functionality? If YES - remove those data-toggle attributes and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yep I wanted the benefit of being able to have links but have a link higlighted based on what page I was on...